# jQuery get aria-checked the value from Google Captcha

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value false from the aria-checked attribute?
I want to check if the aria-checked true or false.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
console.log($("#recaptcha-anchor").attr("aria-checked").val());
```

The full source:

```
<div class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
    <div class="rc-anchor-aria-status">
        <section><h1>recaptcha-status</h1><span id="recaptcha-accessible-status" aria-live="assertive"
                                                aria-atomic="true">reCAPTCHA vereist verificatie</span></section>
    </div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg"></span></div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-content">
        <div class="rc-inline-block">
            <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
                <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox"
                        role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr"
                        aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border"
                                                                      role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-inline-block">
            <div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label"
                                                           id="recaptcha-anchor-label">Ik ben geen robot</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer">
        <div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" role="presentation">
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div>
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/nl/policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy</a>
            - <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/nl/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Voorwaarden</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use `$(':checkbox').attr('aria-checked')` remove the `.val()` it is not a value it is an attr

Comment: its a <span> not a checbox which i want to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log($('#recaptcha-anchor').attr('aria-checked'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label">
```

1. Remove the `.val()` it is not a value it is an attr.
2. Use `$(':checkbox').attr('aria-checked')`

Update

```js
console.log($('#recaptcha-anchor').attr('aria-checked'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
  <div class="rc-anchor-aria-status">
    <section>
      <h1>recaptcha-status</h1><span id="recaptcha-accessible-status" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">reCAPTCHA vereist verificatie</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="rc-anchor-content">
    <div class="rc-inline-block">
      <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
        <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border"
                                                                      role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div
                        class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rc-inline-block">
      <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
        <label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" id="recaptcha-anchor-label">Ik ben geen robot</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer">
    <div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" role="presentation">
      <div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div>
      <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/nl/policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy</a>
      - <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/nl/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Voorwaarden</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: returns undefined console.log($(":checkbox").attr('aria-checked')); its a span

Comment: `$("spanidhere").attr('aria-checked')` use this. update the answer @Bas

Comment: still getting undefined console.log($('#recaptcha-anchor').attr('aria-checked')); @guradio

Comment: Try `$('.recaptcha-checkbox').attr('aria-checked')`. If this doesn't work too, use `.prop()` instead of `attr()`. Ideally `#...` should have worked if the ID is unique.

Comment: @guradio See the question, i have added the complete source. It's the new google captcha

Comment: @Bas see the update you can see the console return `false`

Comment: Thanks @guradio probably something in my code goes wrong.

Comment: @Bas check console for error when you see one you can post here so i can help to fix it :)

Comment: @guradio I think the problem is that the require_once('recaptchalib.php'); at the end is loaded into the page

Comment: @guradio this var elements = $("body").find("[aria-checked='false']"); console.log(elements); returns the object. I can do something here with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114694/discussion-between-guradio-and-bas).